# Composer Autoload Classes from outside vendor

Tags: php, composer-php, autoload

I'm struggling to have my custom classes autoloaded with composer.

my directory structure:

```
--muttley
  --library
    --MyClass.php
  --public
    --index.php
  --vendor
  --composer.json
```

in my composer.json:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Library\\": "library/"
    }
}
```

MyClass.php:

```
namespace Library\MyClass;

class MyClass {

}
```

in index.php:

```
use Library\MyClass;
require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/../vendor/autoload.php';
```

the root directory is defined using `DocumentRoot /www/muttley/public/`. I keep getting the error:

> Fatal error: Class 'Library\MyClass' not found in /var/www/muttley/public/index.php on line 58

Is there anything that I might be missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple mistake. Change:

```
namespace Library\MyClass;
```

to

```
namespace Library;
```

Make sure you have ran `composer dumpautoload` too!